# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed rvm and ruby successfully in a linux environment. When I try to install rail, that time I face following error:

```
$ gem install rails
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/bathakarai in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

My gem version is

> 1.8.25

Rvm version is "rvm 1.18.19 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]".

Please help me by letting me know why this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Finally I got the result. It seems like some sort of proxy problem. I set the proxy using **export "$HTTP_PROXY=IPAddress which is given in browser:portnumber".** 
For any reference http://khylo.blogspot.in/2007/12/ruby-on-rails-headaches.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use to install with below command

> gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo gem install rails
```

This may overcome the permission problem you are having

You also look to be having an internet connectivity problem based on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was avast! Internet Security software on my MacBook Pro. I went to System Preferences, clicked on avast!, clicked on the lock to enable changes, and disabled the Web Shield and File System shield.

After that, I was able to install gems.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled to install rails for two days (I've been getting almost the same error message, but, without that "Insecure world ..." line). And at last I did it using the script below (provided at [RailsGirls](http://guides.railsgirls.com/install/#setup-for-linux)):

```
bash < <(curl -sL https://raw.github.com/railsgirls/installation-scripts/master/rails-install-ubuntu.sh)
```

I don't know why it worked. Just leaving it here with the hope that it will be helpful for some other soul as well. ;P

Answer (score 0):

You should try disabling your IPV6 to install the required Gem file since the rails fetcher could not locate the source. If you are using a linux machine, you can check this link for the steps on how to disable your IPV6 https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu